# Rotate Elegoo 3.5" touchscreen to portrait

Tags: raspbian, touchscreen

I purchased a touchscreen from Elegoo (this one, to be precise https://www.elegoo.com/product/elegoo-3-5-inch-480x320-tft-touch-screen-monitor/) for my Raspberry Pi 3 Model B running the latest Raspbian, got it set up, and have it working perfectly fine at the moment. I followed the instructions and installed the drivers in the disk that came with the screen. Now I'm trying to rotate the screen to portrait mode instead of landscape mode. I've looked around, and I haven't yet found a solution that works. Any help is appreciated, and thanks in advance.

Edit:
I already tried editing config.txt with lcd_rotate and display_rotate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user manual for that display is available [here](https://www.elegoo.com/download/)

A relevant section from it goes like so

[image: instructions]

*[disclaimer] i havent really tried this but i believe it should work if the drivers are correctly setup*